# Error en asignación de variables

Tags: c#, lista

El problema es que si hago:

```
ListaDeListas = {{"1","2","3"},{"4","5","6"},{"7","8","9"}...}

List<string> Lista = new List<string>();

Lista = ListaDeListas[0];
```

Hasta aquí todo bien, entonces es cuando tras:

```
Lista.Add("1");
Lista.Add("2");
Lista.Add("3");
```

Aquí compruebo el valor de `ListaDeListas` y me da:

```
ListaDeListas = {{"1","2","3","1","2","3"},{"4","5","6"},{"7","8","9"}...}
```

Entiendo que en este código el valor de `ListaDeListas` debería permanecer inmutable pero quizás hay algo que me esté perdiendo o algún concepto que tenga erróneo.

¿Por qué sucede esto?

Comment: Capaz con un ejemplo se entienda mejor. Tu codigo debe ir siempre como texto. Yo veo que en cada iteracion a DatosDeElementosDefinitivo se asignan 6 elementos por vuelta.

Comment: Por favor… no pongas capturas de pantalla. No sirven de nada: no se puede poner en un editor de texto, ni compilar, ni buscar texto sobre ellas… sólo sirve para que critiquemos o alabemos tu elección de colores. De todas maneras esta es una página sobre código, no sobre capturas de pantalla ¿Por qué poner capturas en lugar de código? ¡es más complicado! por favor: PON EL CÓDIGO, NO IMÁGENES.

Comment: @gbianchi, y así debería ser, pero se asigna a 6 en la primera, a 9 en la segunda, y a 12 en la tercera iteración. Voy a mejorar la pregunta.

Comment: Ya he quitado la imagen. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Por qué piensas que ListaDeListas debe ser inmutable?

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Roger y Juan Salvador por vuestra respuesta. He probado ambas soluciones que planteáis, tanto asignar los valores en el foreach loop, como declarar la lista en la forma que sugiere Roger, y en ambos casos funciona perfecto. Juan Salvador tu respuesta ha sido muy didáctica. Me he tomado el tiempo para examinarla con calma y creo que ahora entiendo un poquito mejor la lógica de clases. A mi me falta base teórica para programar y a veces algunos conceptos "anti intuitivos" se hacen dificiles de asimilar de primeras. Es genial que haya gente dispuesta ayudar y además en tan poco

Answer (score 7, accepted):

El comportamiento "extraño" que estas viendo, en realidad es completamente normal!

[Según mdsn:](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-Es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/)

> Una clase es un tipo de referencia. Cuando se crea un objeto de la
>   clase, la variable a la que se asigna el objeto contiene solo una
>   referencia a esa memoria. Cuando la referencia de objeto se asigna a
>   una nueva variable, la nueva variable hace referencia al objeto
>   original. Los cambios realizados en una variable se reflejan en la
>   otra variable porque ambas hacen referencia a los mismos datos.

Simplificando.. ¿Qué quiere decir esto?

Al ser, `ListaDeListas` una instancia de la [clase](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/classes) `List<List<T>>` y `Lista` una instancia de [`List<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8) lo antes mencionado aplica completamente.

Al realizar la siguiente igualdad `Lista = ListaDeListas[0];` lo único que estás haciendo es copiar la referencia hacia el objeto, por lo cual, cualquier modificación que sufra la variable `Lista` se va a ver directamente reflejado en `ListaDeListas[0]`.

¿Que debes hacer si queres que `Lista` sea independiente de `ListaDeListas`?

Simplemente la copias, una posibilidad puede ser usando un bucle..

```
foreach (string s in ListaDeListas[0])
         Lista.Add(s);
```

O con Linq podes simplemente usar [`ToList()`](http://using%20System.Linq;) que hace exactamente lo mismo que el bucle anterior, en una sola línea.

Te recomiendo que leas [este artículo](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-Es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/) de mdsn así como [¿Qué son los tipos de referencia?](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) y [¿Qué son los tipos de valor?](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types) ya que son conceptos realmente fundamentales.

Answer (score 4):

> > Error en asignación de variables

Básicamente no es un error. Para poder comprobarlo, se necesita entender dos conceptos claves: [Tipos de referencia](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) y [Tipos de valor](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types).

**Tipos de referencia:**

Hace que cada vez que usemos una variable, se pase una referencia.

Por ejemplo:

```
using System;

class A
{
    public int b = 9;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {       
        A a = new A();  
        Console.Write(a.b);
        A c = a;
        c.b = 10;
        Console.Write(a.b);
    }
}
```

**¿Por qué dio como resultado un 10?**

Esto se debe porqué se le está pasando la referencia del objeto original `a` a `c`. Pero esto es posible porqué el identificador `A` es una clase (las clases en C# son de [tipo de referencia](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types)).

Analicemos el código por partes:

**1. Parte:**

```
A a = new A();
```

El código de arriba lo que hace es crear un objeto y se le asigna la dirección base del objeto al puntero implícito `a`. Por defecto, el atributo `b` tendrá un valor de 9 almacenado.

**2. Parte:**

```
Console.Write(a.b);
A c = a;
```

Se imprime en pantalla el contenido del atributo `b`(un `9`) y además de eso, se le pasa al puntero `c` la dirección de memoria que tenga guardado el puntero `a`. Entonces, como puedes ver, el puntero `c` tiene la referencia original del objeto a que apuntaba el puntero `a`.

**3. Parte:**

```
c.b = 10;
Console.Write(a.b);
```

Como el puntero implícito `c` tiene el mismo contenido de `a`, puedo modificar el atributo del objeto original y por esa razón, imprime un 10, porqué los punteros `a` y `b`, apuntan al mismo objeto.

**Tipos de valor:**

Hace que cada vez que usemos una variable, se pase una copia de los datos.

Por ejemplo:

```
using System;

struct A
{
    public int b;
    public A(int b)
    {
        this.b = b;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {       
        A a = new A(9); 
        A c = a;
        c.b = 10;
        Console.Write(a.b);
    }
}
```

**¿Por qué dio como resultado un 9?**

Esto se debe porqué se está pasando una copia de un dato. Pero esto es posible porqué el identificador `A` es una estructura (los `struct` en C# son de [tipo de valor](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types)).

Analicemos el código por partes:

**1. Parte:**

```
A a = new A(9);
```

El código de arriba hace que el puntero `a` haga referencia a un objeto (donde se le envía un dato al primer parámetro del constructor).

**2. Parte:**

```
A c = a;
```

Esta es la parte más importante, debido a que, no se le estaría pasando la referencia del objeto original (a lo que apunte `a`), sino más bien, se estaría creando un nuevo objeto, esto quiere decir, que el puntero `c` tendrá guardado una dirección base de un nuevo objeto (no es el objeto que apunte `a`). Entonces luego de haberse creado el nuevo objeto, el compilador se encarga de pasar el contenido (los atributos) del objeto original al nuevo objeto (al que apunte `c`).

Para que quede más claro, este código:

```
A c = a;
```

Es equivalente a:

```
A c = new A(0);
c.b = a.b;
```

En el segundo código se refleja más, el funcionamiento:

- Se crea un nuevo objeto.
- Se le pasa una copia de los datos que tenía el objeto anterior, al nuevo objeto.

Con esta explicación, podríamos responder rápidamente tu duda e inquietud.

En el ejemplo que mostraste, estás creando una lista de objetos, solo que cada objeto será de tipo `List<string>` (por esa razón, se le dice lista de listas, es decir, en una lista, tendrás varias listas).

Entonces, como [List](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8) es una clase, será de [Tipo de referencia](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types).

El código que mostraste:

```
Lista = ListaDeListas[0];
```

En realidad lo que estás pasando ahí, es la dirección base del primer elemento que tenga la lista de objetos.

Todo cambio que hagas con el puntero implícito `Lista`, se vera reflejado en `ListaDeListas[0]`. Pero te daré un ejemplo más claro para que lo entiendas mejor.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {       
        List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
        List<string> list2 = new List<string>();
        List<string> list3 = new List<string>();

        List<List<string>> lists = new List<List<string>>();

        lists.Add(list1);
        lists.Add(list2);

        lists[0].Add("1");
        lists[0].Add("2");
        lists[0].Add("3");

        lists[1].Add("4");
        lists[1].Add("5");
        lists[1].Add("6");

        list3 = lists[0];
        list3.Add("1");
        list3.Add("2");
        list3.Add("3");

        foreach(string l in list3)
            Console.Write(l + "\n");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Esto da como resultado:

```
1
2
3
1
2
3
```

**¿Por qué dio ese resultado?**

Para saber el porqué, explicaré paso a paso, el código de arriba.

**1. Parte:**

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
List<string> list2 = new List<string>();
List<string> list3 = new List<string>();
```

Básicamente aquí, es donde se crea 3 lista de objetos de tipo `string`.

**2. Parte:**

```
List<List<string>> lists = new List<List<string>>();
lists.Add(list1);
lists.Add(list2);
```

Se crea la lista de objetos de tipo `List<string>` y después, se añade dos objetos de tipo `List<string>`.

**3. Parte:**

```
lists[0].Add("1");
lists[0].Add("2");
lists[0].Add("3");

lists[1].Add("4");
lists[1].Add("5");
lists[1].Add("6");
```

En ese código se va añadiendo objetos de tipo `string` a los dos listas (`list1` y `list2`) que estén almacenado en la lista de tipo `List<string>`.

Antes de explicar la última parte del código para responder a tu duda, te dibujé la forma como podría estar esto reflejado en memoria:

```
 B1:      
|0x0F| -> B2: |0x0F|0x04|0x05| 
|0xFF| -> B3: |0xFF|0x08|0x09|
```

El bloque 1 (`B1`) es la lista de listas y cada elemento tendrá la dirección base de una lista de objeto de tipo `string`.

El bloque 2 (`B2`) es la lista de tipo `string` y cada elemento tendrá la dirección base del objeto de tipo `string`.

El bloque 3 (`B3`) es la lista de tipo `string` y cada elemento tendrá la dirección base del objeto de tipo `string`.

**3. Parte:**

```
list3 = lists[0];
```

En nuestro mapita de memoria, sabemos que `lists[0]` daría como resultado la dirección `0x0F`, básicamente esa es la dirección que tendrá guardada el puntero `list3`.

**3 Parte:**

```
list3.Add("1");
list3.Add("2");
list3.Add("3");
```

Aquí añadimos 3 objetos de tipo `string` en `list3`. Pero si nos vamos a nuestro mapita de memoria, estaríamos agregando 3 direcciones bases de esos objetos en el bloque 2.

Entonces, nuestro mapita se actualiza:

```
 B1:     
|0x0F| -> B2: |0x0F|0x04|0x05|0x20|0x21|0x22| 
|0xFF| -> B3: |0xFF|0x08|0x09|
```

Como el bloque 2 representa la lista de objetos que maneja `list3`, estaríamos añadiendo las 3 direcciones base de esos objetos en B2.

Ahora, si nosotros imprimimos el contenido del bloque 2 (que básicamente es el bloque que maneja los punteros `list3` y `lists[0]`), nos daría como resultado `123123`.

Por esa razón, nos imprime ese resultado, como `lists[0]` tiene guardado la dirección `0x0F` y `list3` también tiene almacenada esa misma dirección, entonces cualquier cambio se verá reflejado en `B2` (en el bloque 2 de nuestro mapita de memoria, que básicamente es como si fuera la primera lista de objetos de tipo `string`).

Answer (score 2):

Lo que te ocurre es que se realiza una asignación por referencia, por ello los valores de la lista original se alteran.

En vez de hacer esto:

```
List<string> Lista = new List<string>();
Lista = ListaDeListas[0];
```

Prueba con esto

```
List<string> Lista = new List<string>(ListaDeListas[0])
```

Aunque también podrías hace esto:

```
List<string> Lista = new List<string>();
Lista = ListaDeListas[0].ToList;
```